# Select Case VBA not working

Tags: vba, excel, module, intersection

I have the below code which I wish to hide columns based on the case. However it is not working. I suspect it may be to do with the groupings and layout of the sheet however have never come across an issue when using this code before.

```
Private Sub worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2")) Is Nothing Then
    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Password"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Columns("AD:JF").Hidden = False

    Select Case Range("C2").Value2
        Case 1
            Columns("AQ:DC,DR:GD,GS:JE").Hidden = True
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=3
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=2
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1
        Case 2
            Columns("BD:DC,EE:GD,HF:JE").Hidden = True
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=3
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=2
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1
        Case 3
            Columns("BQ:DC,ER:GD,HS:JE").Hidden = True
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=3
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=2
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1
        Case 4
            Columns("CD:DC,FE:GD,IF:JE").Hidden = True
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=3
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=2
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1
        Case 5
            Columns("CQ:DC,FR:GD,IS:JE").Hidden = True
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=3
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=2
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1
        Case 6
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=3
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=2
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1
    End Select
End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password"

End Sub
```

Picture included of spreadsheet layout
[image]

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean?

Comment: To further investigate the problem you might want to remove `On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit`. Also, you might want to include a `Case Else` into your code to catch possible errors or problematic cases: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx

Comment: Out of curiousity, why are you looking at `Range("C2").Value2` , and not `Range("C2").Value` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado Some people believe that there might be a small speed benefit (compared to `.Value`) because it does not require the additional overhead of *format conversion*. Anyhow, we both know that `.Value2` should be the default and not `.Value` and since `C2` does not contain a date nor a currency it doesn't matter either way.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried

```
Columns("AQ:DC,DR:GD,GS:JE").Hidden = True
```

I get an error (Type mismatch), so try to split the hide commands like this:

```
Columns("AQ:DC").Hidden = True
Columns("DR:GD").Hidden = True
Columns("GS:JE").Hidden = True
```

Comment: Using .Range it could be completed in one line `.Range("......").EntireColumn.Hidden = True`